# Custom Extension to upload images for slider in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, module, slider

I want to develop new module by custom code for uploading images and store in database, further i want to use that images in custom areas, like slider or in content area.

I had created half module,right now my module can do:

1. Automatically Create database on installation in phpmyadmin
2. Insert data in database, right now i had given data manually.
3. Shows module in menu, "manage tab" under menu.
4. Manage tab shows list of data stored in module table of database.

Now i am stuck at point to add new data from admin panel.When i click on "add new banner" it must shows form to add new data and store data in database by clicking on Save button.

[image: jtuser bannerslider magento custom module listing]

TIA